# Как сделать Drop-down список (не Snipper)?

Tags: android, java

Добрый день? Подскажите, есть ли красивая реализация выпадающего списка, как на рисунке?
Или мне самому делать на костылях? Bar Sherlock - не подходит.

[image]

Comment: Snipper чем не подходит?

Comment: @Gorets тем, что у него не раскрытие происходит, а открытие диалогового окна, либо я о snipper чего-то не знаю :)

Comment: А вы пользователя не жалеете совсем, да? Но вообще наверное можно сделать простой ListView ? И Show/Hide его?

Comment: @Чад "А вы пользователя не жалеете совсем, да?" - это к чему?

Comment: @Макс Ровкин, Это к тому, что выбор на телефоне(да и на планшете в большинстве случаев) - из выпадалки прибитой к какой-либо части экрана, пальцами - это мало юзабельно. Spinner не просто так придумали, а не для того чтобы насолить разработчикам и мега - пупер дизайнерам. Я бы руки оторвал бы дизайнеру, который предлагает такое решение для мобильного приложения.

Comment: @Чад, А как на счет приложений того же гугла? Я думаю они то уж знаю, что делают

Comment: помойму, это всеравно Snipper, просто на разных апи отображается по разному

Comment: Да если бы, я запускаю сниппер на 4.2.2 и все равно там всплывает диалоговое окно

Comment: @Макс Ровкин, какое мобильное приложение гугл есть с выпадалкой? В гмейле - не выпадалка а меленькая всплывалка :-D 
На сайте которые - тоже или всплывающий попап, или аля клавиатура, но дроп дауна в десктопной версии я не видел.